# Can't copy an already existing Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

Im trying to copy an already existing Database from my Asset folder (Cultureheleper/mobile/src/main/assets/databases) into the System to use it in my Code. 
This is my DBHellper:

```
public class DatabaseCall extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private final static int DB_Version =1;

private static String DB_PATH =  "/data/data/de.gruppe8.culturehelper/databases/";
private final static String DB_Name = "DB.db";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;

/*  private final static String tabelle1 = "Nutzer";

private final static String nutzer_id = "nutzer_id";
private final static String nutzer_name = "nutzer_Name";
private final static String nutzer_email = "nutzer_email";*/

public DatabaseCall(Context context){
    super(context,DB_Name,null,DB_Version );
    Log.i("DB", "anfang gemacht");
    this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{
        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the    default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
            copyDataBase();
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each  time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_Name;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        //database does't exist yet.
    }
    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created  empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_Name);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_Name;

        //myDataBase.close();

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_Name;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
public void Anfrage(String Anfrage){
  /*  String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_Name;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);*/
    Log.i("DB","bis hierhin hat alles funktioniert");
    myDataBase.execSQL(Anfrage);

}

}
```

This is how i call it in the onCreate() from my Mainactivity:

```
    try {
        DB.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {

        DB.openDataBase();

    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        throw sqle;
    }

      DB.Anfrage("SELECT * FROM Ort;");
```

On first Install i get this error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.gruppe8.culturehelper/de.gruppe8.culturehelper.Phone}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Ort(Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Ort;,(OS error - 2:No such file or directory)


  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:  Ort(Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Ort;,(OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
in this Line: myDataBase.execSQL(Anfrage);
```

On Secondd open i get the following Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.gruppe8.culturehelper/de.gruppe8.culturehelper.Phone}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error(Sqlite code 0): Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only.,(OS error - 2:No such file or directory)

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error(Sqlite code 0): Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only.,(OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
In this line:myDataBase.execSQL(Anfrage);
```

Comment: use `rawQuery` instead of `execSQL`, docs say: `'''execSQL Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data'''`

Comment: hi i didn't understand the question you want a new Sqlite file ?

Comment: to pskink: i will try. to Ben_Gratvol, i try to copy an already existing database into my project, so i can use it there. but it doesn't work.

Comment: pskink: Works fine! thanks, maybe you want to write this as a answer so i can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either use `SQLiteDatabase#query` or `SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery` as `SQLiteDatabase#execSQL` is meant for:

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL
>   statement that returns data